# svg dom use variables to define object attributes

Tags: javascript, variables, dom, svg

can you help me? I want to use javascript in order to alter the form of a svg polygon using given variables. I tried this:

```
var example = 200;
document.getElementById('myPolygon').setAttribute('points','50,50 50,100 example,100');
```

It does not work. The double quotation mark doesn't work, either. However, I need the variable because it changes over time. What is the right syntax in this case?

I have looked for such a question, but didn't find it. If there is already a solution for my question provided on this forum, please kindly let me know the link to it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

try this.you should append the value of variable `example` between the string.
if you use `'50,50 50,100 example,100'` ,example is considered as a part of string.`'50,50 50,100 '+example+',100'` here you are adding value of variable `example` to string.

```
document.getElementById('myPolygon').setAttribute('points','50,50 50,100 '+example+',100');
```

Comment: leftside along with answer you will have accept button.you can answer and up vote as well .if you wish :P